# Textbox Error when i will not input data

Tags: c#

how to code if there is no input data in my text box and when i press tab to go the next text box there should be a message that "This fields is required" before proceeding to the next..in my C# code it will save with no data.

Can somebody help me this??
my project is enrollment system.
Thank you

Comment: Please post what you have done and ask for help if you are struck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the TextBox's `Validating` event.

```
private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) {
        MessageBox.Show("This fields is required");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you,i will try on this one, I have the idea but I dont know where to start my code.

Comment: @Koushik, I haven't done about this matter, im still learning the C#

Comment: I try your code but it saves into the database if I press the Add Button eventhough my txtbox1 is null..the message box appears only just to remind.what i want is that It should not be save in the database if its null.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use ASP .Net **RequiredFieldValidator**. 
Please note that this is will validated when the user try to save the data.

Create something like this in your .aspx file

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="This fields is required" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark rate this answer after you confirm it works. Thanks!

Comment: I dont know how to rate your answer since this is my first time in this website.Tell me how.